# jQuery media queries with match media

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, media-queries

I am trying to change my jQuery code depending on screen resolutions. I am animating main content area, and would like to change it's width on different screen sizes.

After a lot of searching online i found something that might be helpful, but i can't get it to work.Here is the code snippet that needs to be changed. It is called Match Media, something like CSS3 media queries, only for JavaScript.

```
  var mq = window.matchMedia( "(max-width: 320px)" );
         if (mq.matches) {
           menuLink.click(function(){
            innerContent.css("display", "none");
            contentWrapper.stop().animate(
                    {width: '40em'},
                    {duration:1200,easing: 'easeOutBack'}
            );
            closeButton.stop().delay(800).animate({opacity:'1'},600,'easeInSine');
            $("#fadeBg").fadeIn();
         });
          }
```

The main thing that i want here is when the max-width criteria is fulfilled to animate the contentWrapper for 40 em. But it seems that nothing is happening.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Are you doing this on document ready?

```
$( function(){
  ...
  var mq = window.matchMedia( "(max-width: 320px)" );

} );
```

Comment: Yes, and above the other call for animating the content.

Answer (score 1):

It worked with me when I added a listener to it.

```
  var mq = window.matchMedia( "(max-width: 320px)" );
  mq.addListener(function(){
    if (mq.matches) {
      ...
    }
  });
```

All wrapped in $(function(){...}); because I used jQuery animations when matched.

Answer (score 0):

this one will work.

```
  $(function () {

//1) create a function 
        var handleMatchMedia = function(md) {
            if (md.matches) {
               // your code
            } else {
               // your code
            }
        }
        var mq = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)");

 // 2) call the function
        handleMatchMedia(mq);


//3) call the addListener function  
        mq.addListener(handleMatchMedia);
      });
```

P.S. the addListener function can be found in Typescript, so make sure you downloaded Typescript .

also read this article:

http://blog.astaz3l.com/2013/11/27/matchmedia/

Answer (score 0):

You can now use the `mediaQuery` object with the `jQuery.prototype.on` event listener since the API is the same as DOM elements.

```js
const mediaQuery = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 400px)');
$(mediaQuery).on('change', (e) => {
  console.log('matches', e.originalEvent.matches);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```