# How can I stop my sidebar from scrolling when on mobile view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a sidebar that scrolls on desktop/iPad view but it also affects it on mobile view I would like to disable this JavaScript code on mobile view/smaller screen.

```
var length = $('#filters-sidebar-wrap').height() - $('#filters-sidebar').height() + $('#filters-sidebar-wrap').offset().top;

      $(window).scroll(function () {

        var scroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        var height = $('#filters-sidebar').height() + 'px';
    
        if (scroll < $('#filters-sidebar-wrap').offset().top) {

            $('#filters-sidebar').css({
                'position': 'absolute',
                'top': '40px',
                'width': '290px'
            });

        } else if (scroll > length ) {

            $('#filters-sidebar').css({
                'position': 'absolute',
                'bottom': '0',
                'top': 'auto',
                'width': '290px'
             });

        } else {

            $('#filters-sidebar').css({
                'position': 'fixed',
                'top': '128px',
                'width': '290px',
                'height': 'height'

            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: I don't see where you're checking screen size. Wouldn't that be the logical approach?

Comment: You can use `matchMedia` for this task. Here is a link to the question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364986/jquery-media-queries-with-match-media

Comment: @isherwood yes I agree I am just stuck on how to implement checking for screen size

Comment: @s.kuznetsov Thank you for suggesting matchMedia, I will try to implement that logic to the code and I would appreciate it if you could help me with the code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem, Thank you for all the help!

```
 if(window.innerWidth < 992 ) {
            $("#filters-sidebar").removeAttr("style");
       
          } else {
      
        /// Add code here
```

Comment: I gave you the answer according to your question, but it turned out that you need something else.